# fragmenttabhost re-createview when tag switch

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

In my recent project, I use the v4 support lib for FragmentTabHost.

When the tab and fragment init, the fragment bound to the tag is created and is rendered. Its lifecycle is

> onCreate ==> onCreateView ==> onActivityCreated

I overrode the onActivityCreated methods, because I need to get some data from api.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Lg.i("on TagDiscoverListFragment activity created");

    new GetDiscoversTask().execute();

}
```

But every time i switch to this tab, this aysnTask executes again, because when switch occurs, the fragment calls:

> onCreateView ==> onActivityCreated

I dont want the data to be refresh again.

Surely, I can extend the FragmentTabHost and override the method doTabChange() and change fragment's Attach/Detach operation to hide/view.

So, any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You should override "onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)" in your fragment
and store data which from api into "outState"

When tab is switched, the onCreateView will be invoked, at this point, you can retrieve api data from "savedInstanceState" (the third argument)